# [Anbox][AWS] "Anbox stream failed Error: lost WebRTC connection" when trying to start session via Anbox Dashboard

Tags: juju, anbox

I've followed the steps to install the Anbox Cloud Appliance in an AWS EC2 instance using https://anbox-cloud.io/docs/howto/install-appliance/aws

I've also created an image of an Android app using the `amc` CLI that appears to have worked as expected. When I try to create a session using the Anbox Dashboard (https://anbox-cloud.io/docs/tut/getting-started-dashboard) loaded in desktop Chrome, I'm experiencing a "Anbox stream failed Error: lost WebRTC connection" issues. When attempting to create a session via the dashboard using Firefox the error is "Anbox stream failed Error: failed to establish a WebRTC connection via ICE".

The relevant container logs are suggest my browser is unable to resolve the ICE candidate host name.

```
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.849372   209 streaming_server.cpp:977] Starting streaming server
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.849406   209 streaming_server.cpp:981] Not connected to supervisor yet, create a connection now
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.851109   209 streaming_server.cpp:990] Connecting to supervisor on wss://240.47.37.26:8082/1.0/sessions/cbmrf0ijdsav5meisn7g/supervisor/socket
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.851416   200 platform.cpp:574] Unhandled anbox event type: 1
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.852012   209 telegraf_backend.cpp:115] Using telegraf server at 192.168.100.1:8095
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox[122]: WiFi support is enabled
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.852174   209 streaming_server.cpp:1171] Creating a new peer connection
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.852226   209 streaming_server.cpp:1217] Using playout delay of min 0ms and max 0ms
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (webrtc_voice_engine.cc:606): Typing detection is requested, but unsupported.
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.855966   209 peer_connection.cpp:168] Using the following STUN/TURN servers:
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.855988   209 peer_connection.cpp:171] stun:3.87.49.14:5349
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.855994   209 peer_connection.cpp:171] turn:3.87.49.14:5349
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox[93]: Cannot apply override for /proc/sys/kernel/sched_tunable_scaling as file doesn't exist
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox[93]: Cannot apply override for /proc/sys/kernel/sched_latency_ns as file doesn't exist
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox[93]: Cannot apply override for /proc/sys/kernel/sched_wakeup_granularity_ns as file doesn't exist
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.860172   209 peer_connection.cpp:235] Setting bitrate allocation constraints: start 7999 Kbit/s max 12122 Kbit/s min 3876 Kbit/s
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.860320   209 peer_connection.cpp:819] Set audio recording to 0
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.860556   209 peer_connection.cpp:815] Set audio playout to 0
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.861711   209 streaming_server.cpp:1283] Everything is setup, ready to stream
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.861748   209 streaming_server.cpp:1097] Idle timer is disabled by configuration
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.861861   209 streaming_server.cpp:1047] Connecting to signaling server at wss://ec2-3-87-49-14.compute-1.amazonaws.com/1.0/sessions/cbmrf0ijdsav5meisn7g/sockets/master/
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.920591   209 libsoup_websocket_client.cpp:52] Successfully connected to websocket
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.920862   209 streaming_server.cpp:1373] Connected to supervisor
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.957854   209 libsoup_websocket_client.cpp:52] Successfully connected to websocket
Aug 06 00:36:23 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:23.957893   209 streaming_server.cpp:749] Successfully connected to signaling server
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (webrtc_media_engine.cc:151): Unsupported RTP extension: {uri: urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level, id: 2}
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:24.599524   218 peer_connection.cpp:732] New stream {e6b5a213-ccbf-4748-ba41-e962f995847a} added
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (audio_send_stream.cc:870): Config is invalid: min_bitrate_bps=-1; max_bitrate_bps=-1; both expected greater or equal to 0
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:24.680258   217 external_audio_device_module.cpp:146] Initializing playout (channels 2 freq 48000Hz)
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (webrtc_voice_engine.cc:606): Typing detection is requested, but unsupported.
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (usrsctp_transport.cc:652): UsrsctpTransport->OpenStream(...): Not adding data stream with sid=0 because stream is already open.
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: I0806 00:36:24.719282   218 peer_connection.cpp:861] Adjusted bitrate for all video and audio encodings on our RTP senders
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (p2p_transport_channel.cc:1304): Failed to resolve ICE candidate hostname c46c9363-ee14-c744-8e2c-7ef2e191fdb8.local with error -3
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (peer_connection.cc:2655): Candidate has an unknown component: Cand[:0:2:udp:2122252542:c46c9363-ee14-c744-8e2c-7ef2e191fdb8.local:59741:local::0:::0:0:0] for mid 0
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (peer_connection.cc:2655): Candidate has an unknown component: Cand[:4:2:tcp:2105524478:c46c9363-ee14-c744-8e2c-7ef2e191fdb8.local:9:local::0:::0:0:0] for mid 0
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (jsep_transport_controller.cc:294): Not adding candidate because the JsepTransport doesn't exist. Ignore it.
Aug 06 00:36:24 ams-cbmrf0mi8v8as7gmvnrg anbox-starter[122]: (p2p_transport_channel.cc:1304): Failed to resolve ICE candidate hostname c46c9363-ee14-c744-8e2c-7ef2e191fdb8.local with error -3
```

Using the chrome://webrtc-internals/ tool, there's a "icecandidateerror" with the description

```
url: stun:3.87.49.14:5349
address: [0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]
port: 64672
host_candidate: [0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]:64672
error_text: STUN server address is incompatible.
error_code: 701
```

This all suggests there's a network issue but it's not clear which layer it's in (between the container and container orchestrator?). How would I figure out where the connection is failing?

My security rules are:

[image]

Comment: did it fix issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was because I had a WebRTC leak shield. Make sure you don't have on any blockers.